# Can main() and its parameters have attributes?

Tags: c++, c++11, attributes, program-entry-point

In standard C++, can the `main` function and its parameters have attributes?

For example, is this following legal?

```
[[noreturn]] int main() { std::abort(); }
```

or something like

```
[[nodiscard, carries_dependency]]
int main(int argc [[maybe_unused]],
         char * argv [[carries_dependency, maybe_unused]] [])
{ /* ... function body omitted ... */ }
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is legal. There is no wording in the C++ standard (in [[basic.start.main]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main), [[dcl.attr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr), or elsewhere) to prevent any of this. One can even mark `main()` as `[[deprecated]]` if wanted.

Comment: Deprecated main made my day

Comment: @PasserBy It is old school.  Modern programmers write code that finishes executing in static initialization.